# Possible to append to ID using ngx-bootstrap's dropdown

Tags: css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

Within the [documentation of ngx dropdown](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#container) they introduce an **append to body** option. I have recently replaced this value to a **table** element instead and it worked.

However, on another page I have **2 tables** on the same page.

So if I was to give each individual table an ID would it be possible to append to an ID table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, but I think it's not possible.
worked around it by making the tables container overflow: visible!important;